# How to know which menu item is clicked in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

I want to know which element was clicked in bootstrap menu.

I have a menu which has dropdown, so I want to know which menu item was clicked and I want to store it in browser local storage how to do this?

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h8970p36/)

I tried this for getting the menu item clicked but it does not work:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert(e.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Also how to store and retrieve thier value from database?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code as well? it will help to provide better answers.

Comment: @AalokMishra added the menu as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a delegate click event to `.dropdown-menu` for the anchors:-

updated [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h8970p36/1/)

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'a', function(e){
  
  // 'this' is the clicked anchor
  
  var text = this.text;
  var href = this.href;
  
  alert(text);
  
  // here add to local storage;
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to be more specific about what elements you want to add a listener to. You have to add a specific class to these elements. Then you can do this easily with jQuery:

```
$(".yourClassName"){
//$(this) will refer to the element
}
```

That way you can store in local storage the content of the clicked element:

```
$(".yourClassName"){
    var value = $(this).text();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    localStorage.setItem(id , value );
    }
```

And that way you retrieve their value:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem(itemId);
```